# Рисование в PIL

Tags: python, pil

Доброго времени суток!

Необходимо на изображении нарисовать квадраты по порядку во весь размер изображения(нашел как нарисовать квадрат), но как его отрисовать на всем изображении не на нашел, так же хотелось бы понять как изменять толщину линий или сделать цвет полупрозрачным

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

#
image = Image.new("RGBA", (100,100), (51,51,51,255))
# это чтобы рисовать на созданном холсте
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

shape = [(10,10),(0,0)]
draw.rectangle(shape, outline="white")

image.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]